# Screen rotate 3 times when back to landscape activity from portrait activity

Tags: android

I have this issue in my tablet device Android 8.1. This device has natural orientation is landscape

I have 2 activity :

A is configured with fullSensor, contains a recyclerview to load items with thumbnail image

B is portrait, contain a surfaceview

```
  <activity
        android:name="com.hdq.myapp.activities.AActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.hdq.myapp.activities.BActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:screenOrientation="fullSensor"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
```

- Step 1 : Open activity A in landscape -> start Activity B : it rotate
  to portrait
- Step 2 : Press Back button, it return to activity A and rotate to
  landscape
- Step 3 : After that, it keep rotate to portrait immmdiately
- Step 4 : Finally, it rotate to landscape again. 3 rotation in just 2 second

It's seem less happen out if A and B is very simple activity (no recylerview, no surfaceview). Just less than before.

This behavior is too weird and I'm not sure where it come from, maybe OS or somewhere my app. The onConfigurationdChanged() method was called 2 time. Another apps in this device are not happen like this. Do you have any idea about this? Is that a memory issue or something like that?

I update the profiler in my device :
[image]

The red one is the first normal rotation. 2 yellow ones is redundant.

This is call chart :

[image]

Comment: Take a look here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47228194/android-8-1-screen-orientation-issue-flipping-to-landscape-a-portrait-screen

Comment: Hey, i have exactly same problem. Can you share how did you solved this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<activity
     android:name="com.hdq.myapp.activities.AActivity"
     android:configChanges="locale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation"
     android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustResize|screenSize"
     android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
     <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

          <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.hdq.myapp.activities.BActivity"
        android:configChanges="locale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustResize"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
```

Comment: Thanks very much, but it doesn't work. Can you explain more about your idea?